# How to Authenticate dynamically to an Azure account using BASH

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli, azure-xplat-cli

I am trying to connect to authenticate to our Azure platform dynamically to run the following commands

```
azure vm show
azure vm restart
azure vm start
azure vm stop
```

To run these commands It seems I have to authenticate manually via a browser using Azure's dynamically generated code, returned from the execution of the Azure login command.

Is there a way to authenticate dynamically without manual intervention? We would ideally like to do this via a BASH script if possible.

Note: We don't need to do this with AD accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-connect/), and according to the experience, there are two ways to do that - using azure login (auth using dialogue, not the dynamic as you describe that), and using publish settings file which you may use for management without need to login in the browser.

```
azure account download
azure account import <path to your .publishsettings file>
```